# Can the Postman collection be exported in json format with tests not wrapped in events?

Tags: json, testing, postman, newman

I'm facing the problem when contributing to a Postman collection that has been created by different people, long time ago. The JSON file that was created, has a different structure and format from what I get when I export a collection in Postman (regardless of the exported collection version) - even if I import and export the same file.

The problem is that the Newman version we have on our server, does not execute tests that are wrapped in events in an exported collection - like this:

[image: test scripts in events format]

An example to show the format:

```
"event":[  
   {  
      "listen":"test",
      "script":{  
         "type":"text/javascript",
         "exec":[  
            "tests[\"Status code is 200\"] = responseCode.code === 200;",
            ""
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

It requires the "name-value" pairs like this:

[image: test scripts in "name-value" format]:

```
"tests":"tests[\"First test\"] = responseBody.has(\"first\");\ntests[\"Second test\"] = responseBody.has(\"second\");"
```

How can I get such a format (the **last** example) without rewriting my tests manually in the JSON file, which is not the way out for a big amount of new tests?

Comment: I kinda don't really know what the problem is here exactly? The older file format? The newer exported file? The older style of 'tests' within the file? The Newman version? I'm just confused. How was the original file created?

Comment: Danny, the thing is that I can't figure out how the original file was created, and I need to know it in order to contribute to the tests in the same format.

Comment: Seems more counter productive to be finding a solution to shoe horn tests, into a file type that is not compatible with the newer versions of both Postman and Newman.